# Matricial form of multidimensional GBM

Tags: matrix-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\mu \in \mathbb R^d$ and $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_d \in \mathbb R^k$. Let $W^{\mathbb P}$ be a $k$ dimensional brownian motion. We say that $S_t$ is a geometric brownian motion over $\mathbb R^d$ if the components $S_t^i$ of $S_t$ satisfy the SDE
$$
\mathrm d S_t^i=S_t^i \mu_i  \mathrm d t+S_t^i\sigma_i \cdot \mathrm dW^{\mathbb P} \qquad i=1,\ldots, d. \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
I was trying to write such an expression in matricial form. If we indicate by $\Sigma \in \mathbb R^{d\times k}$ the matrix whose rows are $\sigma_1,\ldots \sigma_d$, this SDE can be written as
$$
\mathrm dS_t=(\mu+\Sigma \mathrm dW^{\mathbb P})*S_t,
$$
where $*$ denotes the Hadamard (or pointwise) product.

**Question**: Is there a simple way of writing $(\dagger)$ in matricial form without resorting to the Hadamard product? My guess is *probably not*. If the answer is negative, can we express it through tensors?